# GA Virtual pageview on Webform reload: is there an easier way?

Tags: 7, webforms, google-analytics

I can't believe it was so difficult.

I have [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) installed. I want to track submissions of my webform, but since it's set to reload current page on submission, I must make use of either Virtual Pageviews or Events. I went with the former.

At first I thought it'll be as easy as using `hook_webform_submission_insert()`[1](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and invoking GA code via `drupal_add_js()` from there, but somehow it didn't work: the hook itself was executed, but JS was never added to the page.

Now I reached the bottom of Google and haven't found any help on this specific case (everybody seems to be using separate "thank you" pages). Fast forward a couple hours, dozen approaches and hundreds of pages, I finally arrived at this working code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //add custom submit callback
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_[node id here]') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_submit_ga';
  }

  //add GA tracking upon successful submission
  if (isset($_SESSION['mymodule_submission_successful']) &&
      $_SESSION['mymodule_submission_successful'] == TRUE) {
    //reset temporary variable
    unset($_SESSION['mymodule_submission_successful']);
    //build JS
    $script = '(function() {';
    $script .= '_gaq.push(["_trackPageview","[virtual page path here]"]);';
    $script .= '})();';
    //add JS somewhere in the end
    drupal_add_js($script, array("type"=>"inline","group"=>JS_THEME,"weight"=>20));
  }
}

function mymodule_submit_ga($form,&$form_state) {
  //set temporary variable for the code above
  $_SESSION['mymodule_submission_successful'] = TRUE;
}
```

I'm sharing this in case it helps anybody, but as I'm not a PHP expert, I can't help the feeling that I missed something really simple.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier method (that requires no coding) would be to set the webform's "Redirection location" setting to "Custom URL" and enter 'node/%nid?f=my_webform_success'.

This will post the form to itself and also allow you to add some unique key/value to the URL.

Then within Google Analytics you can set a Goal with the Goal URL set to 'f=my_webform_success' and the Match Type set to "Regular Expression Match".